# How can i set a condition based on database value to add a new user in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have three users **Admin Reseller and User**. Now Admin creates both Reseller and User. So Admin add user for a specific reseller. Reseller has a filed in database called **Allocation Block** This is a max value of **users a reseller can have** So I add my users in user controller,there i want to check a condition that if i am adding a user for XYZ reseller, then i must check the allocation block value. if its greater than it the show a error message and not allow to add that user.

Below is my code to add a user :

Controller:

```
public function add_user()
 { 

            $usertype = $this->session->userdata('usertype'); 
            $this->load->model('reseller_m'); 

            if ($usertype == "admin") { 
            $this->data['user'] = $this->user_m->get_new(); 
            $rules = $this->user_m->rules_admin; 
            $rules['password']['rules'] .= '|required'; 
            $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules); 

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) { 

            $data = $this->user_m->array_from_post(array('sip_id', 'sip_pass', 'name', 'key', 'email', 'password', 'phone', 'status', 'created', 'balance')); 
            $data['password'] = $this->user_m->hash($data['password']); 

            $key = $this->user_m->save($data, $id); 
            redirect('admin/user'); 
            } 

            $resellers = $this->reseller_m->get_drop_down(); 
            if(count($resellers) > 0) { 
            foreach($resellers as $value) { 
            $dropdown[$value->key] = $value->key; 
            } 
            } 
            $this->data['resellers'] = $dropdown;



            $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/add'; 
            $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data); 
            } else { 
            $this->load->view('permission'); 
            } 
            }
```

The Add View of Users:

```
<h3><?php echo empty($user->id) ? '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Add a Reseller' : 'Edit User ' . $user->name; ?></h3>
        <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
        <?php echo form_open(); ?>
        <table class="table">

            <tr>
                <td>SIP Username</td>
                <td><?php echo form_input('sip_id', set_value('sip_id', $user->sip_id)); ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>SIP Password</td>
                <td><?php echo form_input('sip_pass', set_value('sip_pass', $user->sip_pass)); ?></td>
            </tr>



        <tr> 
        <td>Key</td> 
        <td> 
        <?php echo form_dropdown('key', set_value('key', $resellers,$user->key));?>
        </td> 
        </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><?php echo form_input('name', set_value('name', $user->name)); ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td><?php echo form_input('email', set_value('email', $user->email)); ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><?php echo form_password('password'); ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Confirm password</td>
                <td><?php echo form_password('password_confirm'); ?></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>Balance</td>
            <td>Yes<?php echo form_radio('balance','Yes', $this->input->post('balance') ? $this->input->post('balance') : $user->balance);  ?> No <?php echo form_radio('balance','No', $this->input->post('balance') ? $this->input->post('balance') : $user->balance);  ?></td>   
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Phone</td>
                <td><?php echo form_input('phone', set_value('phone', $user->phone)); ?></td>
            </tr>



            <tr>
                <td>Status</td>
                <td><?php echo form_dropdown('status', array('Active' => 'active', 'Inactive' => 'inactive', 'Delete' => 'delete'), $this->input->post('status') ? $this->input->post('status') : $user->status ); ?></td>  
            </tr>



            <tr>
                <td>Created</td>
                <td><?php echo form_input('created', set_value('created', $user->created)); ?></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Save', 'class="btn btn-primary"'); ?></td>
            </tr>


        </table>
        <?php echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: I have managed to get all the allocation block values from database i just want to check at the time of adding a user that allocation block value ifs greater than the total users in his account

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in the user table you must have a column to indicate to the corresponding reseller id for a particular user. So you should add that column in your table if it doesn't exist already. 
Then in the model, you can add a function to count the users by reseler id.

```
function reseler_users_count($reseler_id){//count users by reseller
    $this->db->where('key', $reseler_id);
    return $this->db->count_all_results('users_tbl');
    //DB Query: Select * FROM users_tbl WHERE key = '$reseller_id';
    //return number of rows
}
```

Also in your model, add a function that checks the allocation block value and compares it with the number of users already registered for that reseller. It returns true or false, but you can modify it to return registered users or false, or whatever.

```
function check_reseller_allocation($reseler_id){
    $this->db->select('allocation_block');
    $this->db->where('id', $reseler_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('reselers_tbl');
//DB QUERY: SELECT 'allocation_block' FROM 'reselers_tbl' WHERE 'id' = $reseller_id;
    $reseler = $query->row();// Get row (it should be only one row, but I didn't add the condition though; you can add if($query->num_rows() == 1) )
    $allocation_block = $reseler->alocation_block; 
    $reseller_users = $this->reseler_users_count($reseler_id);//call reseler_users_count() to find users registered for this reseller
    if($reseller_users < $allocation_block)return TRUE;//is the number of users registered with ('key' = $reseller_id) is smaller then the ALLOCATION BLOCK, return TRUE else return FALSE;
        return FALSE;
}
```

Then your controller would look something like this:

```
     public function add_user() { 

            $usertype = $this->session->userdata('usertype'); 
            $this->load->model('reseller_m'); 

            if ($usertype == "admin") { 
                $this->data['user'] = $this->user_m->get_new(); 
                $rules = $this->user_m->rules_admin; 
                $rules['password']['rules'] .= '|required'; 
                $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules); 

                if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
                    if($this->reseller_m->check_reseller_allocation($reseller_id)){//check_reseller_allocation will return TRUE if ALLOCATION BLOCK value is not reached (so you can add another user) and FALSE if it is reached, so you cannot add another user
//if TRUE (you can add one more). then the script continues, adding the user
                        $data = $this->user_m->array_from_post(array('sip_id', 'sip_pass', 'name', 'key', 'email', 'password', 'phone', 'status', 'created', 'balance'));
                        $data['password'] = $this->user_m->hash($data['password']); 

                        $key = $this->user_m->save($data, $id); 
                        redirect('admin/user'); 
                    }else{//if FALSE (ALLOCATION BLOCK val is reached) display some error view; I called it 'max_allocation', but you may call it whatever you want
                     $this->load->view('max_allocation');}
                } 

                $resellers = $this->reseller_m->get_drop_down(); 
                if(count($resellers) > 0) { 
                    foreach($resellers as $value) { 
                        $dropdown[$value->key] = $value->key; 
                    } 
                } 
                $this->data['resellers'] = $dropdown;
                $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/user/add'; 
                $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data); 
            } else { 
                $this->load->view('permission'); 
            } 
        }
```

**EDIT:** I had mistaken the table name in `reseler_users_count()`. Now it's OK. You must change 'users_tbl' with actual name of the users table. Same for 'reselers_tbl', cange it with the actual name of the resellers table. Also, both functions take as parameter the id of the reseller.  In `add_user()` controller function, you must have that value. Maybe you should pass with  $_POST.

Comment: i have a field called key that maps a reseller to his/her users.

Comment: i didnot understood the model method! can you please add a little description

Comment: First if  $reseller_users is greater than allocation block return false so that stop the execution of script?

Comment: I updated the answer. To be more explicit than that, you must show me the form view.

Comment: Also i have an idea please see firstly we can show how much users a reseller can avail through his max_allocation value. now if he currently has lesser users then we show him a button to request more users where he will insert the no of users he want. once he add that we show that request in admin account so admin will have two buttons approve or cancel if he hits approve then automatically creates that number of request users.

Comment: Please see if you can help me with this

Comment: @Rajan, not earlier then Monday. We talk again on Monday, OK?